# Recommendations - OpenSeaDragon / PureRef hybrid

Tags: images, software-recommendation

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any open source projects that have an infinitely zoomable/panable canvas (like PureRef), but allows for a "tiled" image source. That is, the images would be ingested and broken into tiled that correspond to the various zoom levels. This allows for a nearly infinite number of images as you're only feeding the pixels needed for a given area at a given zoom level.

OpenSeaDragon's "Collection Mode" captures the essence of what I'd like, but I'd also like to be able to perform transformations on individual images like in PureRef - moving, scaling, rotating, etc.

For reference:
https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-collection/ 
https://www.pureref.com

Any thoughts are appreciated!